# How To Prevent Disable and enable buttons in Angular application during builds

Tags: angular

I have an angular application where buttons can be enabled and disabled during production how to prevent 
any input taken from browser tools

Comment: You mean the developer tools of the browser?

Comment: <button disabled>Click me</button> i can modify the disabled property to enableand excute some action

Comment: you can also add right click disable event in browser , though other can still open developer tools by other shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Frontend , you can add a **same logic** that you **used to disable a button** in the click event **function** of the button. so even if some updates the html still in click event it will fail the condition.

But Backend must have validations for all error case.

```
<button [disabled]="condition > 2" (click)='submit()' > 2">Submit</button>
```

in ts.

```
submit(){
 if(this.condition < 2){
 // then add logic 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to disable the button in a way, that it can not be modified from the developer tools of a browser. I mean if there is `<button disabled>Click me</button>` a code snippet, the `disabled` property can be removed and the button can be clicked.

All you can do about this is to validate all requests on backend side. If the button is disabled and the backend receives a request that should have come from an enabled button, the backend should respond with a `400 Bad Request`.

Note that on client side the JavaScript code can be tampered as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable every input by  < input [disabled]="yourBoolean" ...

Better:

You can display a dialog with message text via [mat-dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)  (options : {disableClose:true, closeOnNavigation:false}) to prevent changes on input fields.

When you decide that users can use the app again, you can close the dialog programmatically.